# setLocale not working on symfony2 application

Tags: symfony

I followed this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html) instructions to make locale changes "sticky'.

And created an action to change the locale with user request.

The **LocaleListener** class

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 15)),
        );
    }
}
```

**The directory structure:**

[image]

**The service**

```
services:
     app.locale_listener:
            class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
            arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

**The Action**

```
/**
     * @Route("/change-locale/{locale}", name="change_locale", defaults={"locale" = "it"})
     */
    public function changeLocaleAction(Request $request) {

        $request->setLocale('it');

        $ref = $request->headers->get('referer');
        return $this->redirect($ref);
    }
```

But its not working, and I am not getting any errors. Why might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting the `_locale` attribute in your request listener, but in your route definition the attribute being set is `locale` (note the missing leading underscore).

You need to update your route definition accordingly:

```
/**
 * @Route("/change-locale/{_locale}", name="change_locale", defaults={"_locale" = "it"})
 */
public function changeLocaleAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: the `locale` is just the slug. Something is wrong with the `setLocale` method.

Comment: In this case, your locale listener is pretty useless. What exactly did you expect to happen after calling the `setLocale()` method?

Comment: So with every request I should send also the `_locale` parameter?

Comment: I saved the on value on session `$request->getSession()->set('_locale', $request->get(locale));`